# How to put a texture on a UILabel text

Tags: uilabel

I would like to have a texture on UILabel.text .

Doing so I subclassed UILabel. Using the -drawTextInRect method, I am trying to get only the text for creating an image mask with the function CGImageMaskCreate.

Once having that image mask from text I am trying to use it to create a new image by calling the function CGImageCreateWithMask.

Is that even possible?

Is that the right approach?

How do I get an image mask from the UILabel.text?

Answer (score 3):

You can just set text color to pattern image:

```
label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture"]];
```

Result:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It may help you.

```
lbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
```